# Mpabox GL case expression output, perform math expression

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hi the issue is not to return output after condition is met, just to apply some math operation and return the result of it to text-field.
Mapboxgl-js version v 1.11.0

```
  "text-field": [
     "case",
    ['all', [">=",   ["abs", ["get", "count"]], 1.0e+3]], //if thousands
   
    ["/", ["get", "count"], 1.0e+3], //<--- doesn't work perform division, should return 1 if count is 1000
    
     ["get", "count"] //fallback value 
   ],
```

Comment: Hi Ben, I _think_ what you're trying to accomplish is to show `1.2` if count is `1200` but keep `700`, for example (anything under 1000) as is? Can you try just `"text-field": ["/", ["get", "count"], 1000]` just see if this works by itself? Then we can try adding the condition back. If this is not what you're asking, could you try rewording the question, maybe adding the full style and if possible a sample map?

Comment: Also, could you mention what platform this is using (iOS, Android, JS)? And in case it's JavaScript, also tell us if you're pointing the map to a JSON file of the style or passing the style object directly to the map? If you're using JSON (no matter which platform), **remove the comments** (if they're in the original code), and also substitute `'all'` for `"all"`, as JSON does not support single quotes.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, We use mapbogl-js, v 1.11.0 thank you for your time and will to help, i have solved this, the issue was, with output type for case expression, so once i updated the output of division operation to be of type string, everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Comes out the issue was with types, i tried to perform Math operations in case expression output without bringing it to type number, after adding "to-string"(for result), and "number"(for operation itself) it was solved, and formatting works great.
Here is the working solution.

```
    "text-field": [
    "case",
     // Billions  
    ["all", [">=",   ["abs", ["get", "usersCount"]], 1.0e+9]], 
    // divide usersCount by 1 billion, than strigify("to-string"), and concat result with string "B" same for all
    ["concat", ["to-string", ["round", ["/", ["number", ["get", "usersCount"]], ["number", 1000000000]]]], 'B'],
    
    ["all", [">=",   ["abs", ["get", "usersCount"]], 1.0e+6]],
    ["concat", ["to-string", ["round", ["/", ["number", ["get", "usersCount"]], ["number", 1000000]]]], "M"] ,

    ["all", [">=", ["abs", ["get", "usersCount"]], 1.0e+3]],
    ["concat",["to-string",  ["round", ["/", ["number", ["get", "usersCount"]], ["number", 1.0e+3]]]], "K"],
    //if none of above (1-10) return the value itself 
    ["get", "usersCount"]
  ],
```

Hope this will help someone